# Create dynamic Table in Worddocument with Excel VBA Macro depending on filled Lines

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am building an Excel-Tool where you'll have an inputmask. After being done and clicking on "Execute" it will automatically create directories inclusive worddocuments from templates by predefined textmarkers.
Now the Problem:

In these templates are tables and I only want to give these tables as much lines as they really need and I am totally out of any idea how to solve that. Find the code for filling automatically below:

```
Public Function Txtmkr_SDD()

Dim appWord             As Object 'Word-Instance
Dim wdDoc               As Object 'Word-Document
Dim wdRngE              As Object 'Word-Range 1
Dim wdRngR              As Object 'Word-Range 2
Dim wdRngC              As Object 'Word-Range 3
Dim wdRngCN             As Object 'Word-Range 4

Dim wks                 As Worksheet 'Excel-Worksheet
Dim AdresseCE           As String
Dim neueAdresseCE       As Long
Dim Processname1        As String
Dim Processname2        As String
Dim Version             As String

Dim IDPath As String
If TB_ID.Value = vbNullString Then TB_ID = IDPath Else IDPath = (TB_ID.Value) & Chr(32)


'*** Word start ***
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'*** opens File ***
Set wdDoc = appWord.Documents.Add(Template:=Worksheets("StartPage").Cells(48, 4) & "\Document_Templates\SDD_Template.dotx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

'*** Word visible ***
appWord.Visible = True

'*** just in case Document is protected ***
'doc.Unprotect

'*** Jump to Textmarker in Word ***
'*** Check of existence ***
'*** Take Value from "CopyData" Cell "B1" and insert Textmarker ***
If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Processname1") Then
    With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Processname1")
        Set wdRngE = .Range
        wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(1, 2).Value
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Processname1", wdRngE
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Missing Link [Processname1]."
End If

  '*** Take Value from "CopyData" Cell "B2" and insert Textmarker ***
If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Processname2") Then
    With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Processname2")
        Set wdRngE = .Range
        wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(2, 2).Value
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Processname2", wdRngE
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Missing Link [Processname2]."
End If


  If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("SDDVersion") Then
    With wdDoc.Bookmarks("SDDVersion")
        Set wdRngE = .Range
        wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(3, 2).Value
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "SDDVersion", wdRngE
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Missing Link [Version]."
End If


      If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("Create_Date") Then
    With wdDoc.Bookmarks("Create_Date")
        Set wdRngE = .Range
        wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(4, 2).Value
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "Create_Date", wdRngE
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Missing Link [Create_Date]."
End If


          If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("SDDAuthor") Then
    With wdDoc.Bookmarks("SDDAuthor")
        Set wdRngE = .Range
        wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(6, 2).Value
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "SDDAuthor", wdRngE
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Missing Link [Author]."
End If




          If wdDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("ProcessID") Then
    With wdDoc.Bookmarks("ProcessID")
        Set wdRngE = .Range
        wdRngE.Text = Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(20, 2).Value
        wdDoc.Bookmarks.Add "ProcessID", wdRngE
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "Missing Link [Author]."
End If

'*** Set Time_Date and SDD Path ***
 Dim time_date As String
 time_date = Format(Date, "yyyy_mm_dd")
 Dim SDD As String
 Dim shp As Shape

'*** Define SDD as Filename ***
SDD = (time_date & "_" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(1, 2).Value & "_" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(21, 2).Value & "_" & Worksheets("Helper#3").Cells(3, 2).Value & "_" & "V" & Worksheets("CopyData").Cells(3, 2).Value & ".docx")

'*** Dim wdApp As Word.Application ***
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
'*** Set up SavePath & Filename ***
appWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Worksheets("Variables").Cells(3, 8).Value & "\" & IDPath & (Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(1, 1)) & "\" & Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(3, 3).Value & "\" & Worksheets("Setup#2_DirectoryList").Cells(14, 21).Value & "\" & SDD

'*** Updates the Footer in Word ans saves the file ***
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
With appWord.ActiveDocument
    .Fields.Update
    .PrintPreview
    .ClosePrintPreview

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
appWord.ActiveDocument.Save

 For Each shp In doc.Shapes
    With shp.TextFrame
        If .HasText Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields.Update
        End If
    End With

Next

End With

'*** Word quit ***
appWord.ActiveDocument.Close
appWord.Quit

'*** set Variables free ***
Set wdRngE = Nothing
Set wdRngR = Nothing
Set wdRngC = Nothing
Set wdRngCN = Nothing
Set wdRng = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
Set sFolder = Nothing  
End Function
```

This one is working like it should, for normal textmarkers, but now I need dynamic tables, because even if the input gives maybe 20 lines for content - it hasn't to be filled completely in the final worddocument.

Would be very nice if someone knows how to do that.

Beside that: thx Harassed Dad for editing ;-)

In order for further requests; this is what it looks like at the moment (the excel sheet where the macro is running)

[Excel-Tool with Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzIJy.jpg)
[The Macro needs to give more rows if there are indeed 10 Credential-Entries, but there should also be only 3, 4 etc, so i am looking for a way to add them dynamically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No2nH.jpg)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "but now I need dynamic tables". Do you mean the number of rows and/or columns may vary? Where's the data coming from and how what code would you use to "read" it?

Comment: I edited the main post for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

First you need create bookmark by select whole table in template file and add Bookmark
[image]

```
Sub test()
        Dim WA As Object, WD As Object
        TempFolder = ThisWorkbook.path & "\Temp\"
        TemplateName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\file.docx"
            Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                'WA.Visible = False
            Set WD = WA.Documents.Add(TemplateName)
                With WD
                    If IsBM(WD, "Table_Info") Then ' Check if Bookmark Exist
                        With .Bookmarks.Item("Table_Info").range.Tables(1) ' Work on Table Bookmarked as Table_Info
                            ColN = 1
                            For RowN = 1 To 10
                                .Rows(RowN).Cells(ColN).range.Text = "Col= " & ColN & " Row= " & RowN '"Column1RowN"
                                .Rows(RowN).Cells(ColN + 1).range.Text = "Col= " & ColN & " Row= " & RowN '"Column2RowN"
                                .Rows(RowN).Cells(ColN + 2).range.Text = "Col= " & ColN & " Row= " & RowN '"Column3RowN"
                            Next RowN
                        End With
                        .Bookmarks.Item("Table_Info").Delete
                    End If
                End With
            WD.SaveAs TempFolder & "1.docx"
            WD.Close False
            Set WD = Nothing
            WA.Quit False
            Set WA = Nothing
    End Sub


    Function IsBM(ByVal WDs As Object, ByVal BookMarkName As String) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
            IsBM = WDs.Bookmarks.Exists(BookMarkName)
    End Function
```

Comment: When I try this I'll get "RuntimeError 13"
I directly set "BookMarkName" as Bookmark and defined a Range as "Table_Info" (just for testing)

Comment: It probably because you dont have template file in needed folder

Comment: tried the new code, i will try tomorrow again, head is exploding for today :-) Thanks to all who tried to help - I am fine to publish the document here when it's finished.